# connect 150w output of amplifier to the input of my pc

Tags: recording

hai
   my amplifier rated an output of 150w, can i connect it to the input of my pc (ordinary sound card, single input)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't you amplifier has a line-out or headphone output?

If you connect the 150W to the line-in on your sound card, you will probably burn it instantaneously. The input for sound is usually very low.

Comment: no yaaar....dere isn't any headfone output for my amplifier..

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. You could put enough resistance in the circuit to get your amp's signal down to something your sound card won't find offensive.  BUT - then you've got to find some way to dissipate a LOT of heat coming from that in-line resistance. What you probably want to do instead is split the input to your amp and send that low voltage signal to your PC.